# Rotate opengl tetrahedron around its center?

Tags: opengl, rotation

I've been asked to draw a 3D tetrahedron and make it rotate around x, y or z axes, depending on the input give. Now I have 2 questions.

1) I drew my tetrahedron using GL_TRIANGLES (4 triangles). Is this the better way of drawing primitives that will be transformed?

2) I belive (from other questions I've seen) that axis rotation is about translating to that specific axis, something like (0, -y, -z), then rotate around that axis and finally translate back. Ok now, what should be values for translating? y, z? I have lots of values representing each vertex, do I translate them all?

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be faster to just write complete answer than ask a lot questions:

1. To ease and speed things up a bit, use `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN` or  `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` instead.
2. Depends on the pipeline you are using:

   *2.1* Old OpenGL (< 2.0, shaderless)

   You shouldn't translate and rotate them by hand. Use appropriate `glRotate` and `glTranslate` functions. Values you need to pass to these functions are obviously related to desired position and rotation of your object; you will find more about them in documentation.

   *2.2* Programmable pipeline

   Create a transformation matrix (either by yourself or by using library such as GLM) and pass it as uniform to vertex shader.

And oh, you don't *translate to an axis*. You multiply the current view matrix by appropriate rotation matrix.

You should try to read a bit more before digging into more complicated topics. [This tutorial](http://arcynthesis.org/gltut) covers modern OpenGL very well; if you are forced to use old OpenGL, take a look at [NeHe tutorials](http://nehe.gamedev.net) instead.

Comment: Regarding 1.) Modern GPUs are optimized for indexed triangle rendering, so there's no noticeable difference in performance between GL_TRIANGLES and the other GL_TRIANGLE_… primitives (it takes some serious corner cases to get some measureable difference, if using VBOs). If using client side vertex arrays the measureable difference comes mostly from bandwidth limitation effects of the system bus.

Comment: @datenwolf "**ease** and speed". Think 5? 6? vertices instead of 12. It certainly won't be *slower*.

Comment: If that tetrahedron is to be drawn with illumination, then you're back to 12 vertices, as for each face you have different vertices (a vertex is the whole tuple of position, normal, and the other attributes).